# TCP socket connection as a service

Tags: android, tcp

i tried searching a lot and gave up.
i have a TCP client class which basically connects to server.
i call this tcp client class from my main activity and using async thread from main activity i run a method in tcp client class and things goes fine.
i have a another activity which needs to send a message by calling a method in this tcp client class but i am unable to do.
please help.

i thought of converting my tcp client class as service but in that case i am not sure how to keep the method running which listens for incoming messages.
please help.

i used this TCP client class and same main activity
http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.pt/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html

also i have to include the functionlity of sending images through this TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your TCP connection code in a service, then connect from Activity as needed. For example look into [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)

So what will happened is when needed you main activity will connect to this service and disconnect when going into onPause state and the another activity which is on foreground will take over look for the service bound itself and do what you what that to do.

Comment: It worked.Thank you so much,I realise that i have long way to go.8 hours i spent and you solved in few minutes.

Comment: i have a question. if i bind that service in two activities, then will there be two instances of connctions created?

Comment: I believe that will depend on your implementation. I think it is important to have Service to Server communication stable and not worry much about Activities to Service. I guess you can follow some way to reuse the same connection (Activity to Service) if you want to.

Comment: i request you to please check the main activity of this http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.pt/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html. how to convert this mainactivity to use service.(problem is that listeming interface) now as i have converted TCPconnection class to service.

Comment: @user2193101 Any discussion concerning this question should take place here, not privately, so all may benefit, and you shouldn't expose your email address in public places unless you love spam email.

Comment: well [link](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.pt/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html) in this tutorial they have a method in main activity implemented from TCPClient class. as @minhaz said i am able to convert that TCPclient class into a service class and i am able to bind with another activities but not with main activity as i am confused with line 65-71 in Myactivity class in tutorial

Comment: also google documentation says that bound service doesnot live indefinitely.i want service to live indefinitely. how to goahead?reason is if everytime service starts my server identifies it as new client and it becomes problem in handling it

Comment: I am having a similar issue...How to keep the socket open and the service running even though the activity is being destroyed and recreated (orientation change)